# Read data from a database in vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

So I used this piece of sample code to retrieve data from a MS Access Database and display it on a few textboxes on the form. The following error occurs -

> @ dr = cmd.ExecuteReader - Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
>   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

This is the sample code -

```vb
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Public dr As OleDbDataReader

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\example\Desktop\Data.accdb" ' Change it to your Access Database location
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
End Sub

Dim r As Random = New Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myConnection.Open()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE (Code = '" & r.Next(1, 3) & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        TextBox1.Text = dr("Description").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dr("Cost").ToString
        TextBox3.Text = dr("Price").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like it's unable to automatically convert the type of data that is in r.Next(1,3) to the type of data that is in the Code column.  What are those data types?

Comment: Code - Text, 
Description - Text,
Cost - Currency,
Price - Currency,

Comment: On executereader I am getting "The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Items'."

Comment: This is the link to the Access table - http://www.winlockpro.org/PasswordGenData.accdb

Comment: all the items are available in the database and everything is spelled out correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name in the file that you provided for download is "Table1" not "Items".

Change the query string to:

`str = "SELECT * FROM Table1 where (Code = '" & r.Next(1, 3) & "')"`

Comment: I just wanted to add another error 
'An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'

Comment: Can't seem to figure out why, it occurs only sometimes

Answer (score 3):

Try this ..

str = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE (Code = '" & (r.Next(1, 3)).ToString() & "')"

Comment: I tried both methods mentioned and I still get the same error.

Comment: http://www.winlockpro.org/PasswordGenData.accdb this is the link to the database.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

str = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE (Code = '" & cStr(r.Next(1, 3)) & "')"